# The lattice of $y^2=x(x-1)(x-λ)$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms

We know that every elliptic curve is associated with a lattice. So is the lattice of $y^2=x(x-1)(x-λ)$ just the lattice spanned by $\{0,1,λ\}$?

If yes, is there some direct explanation? (Do not compute $g_2, g_3$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. People usually go the other way: given the elliptic curve $E_{\tau} = \mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \tau)$, they compute $\lambda$ as a function of $\tau$. In this guise it's called the [modular lambda function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function) $\lambda(\tau)$, and is naturally a modular function of level $2$. I would be surprised if there were any particularly natural formula for its inverse as a function of $\tau$.

Comment: Check out https://books.google.com/books?id=hYQECAAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=inverse+of+modular+lambda+function&source=bl&ots=Dqr2rOvKF3&sig=XgJqUo68B8YqVgElApXOSYXIX9M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdgIHolOLJAhVFPiYKHZ_-CwkQ6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=inverse%20of%20modular%20lambda%20function&f=false so perhaps it is not terrible? I know little of such things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So is there any formula for λ(τ) ?

Comment: @Akatsuki: at the Wikipedia article you can see several formulas in terms of other special functions. Nothing particularly simple though, I think.

Comment: The period $\tau$ is the ratio of hypergeometric functions of $\lambda$ (two independent solutions to the Picard--Fuchs equation for this family, which in this case is a particular hypergeometric equation).